# Unix command to print a data between two matching patterns

Tags: linux, unix

I have a text file which has multiple start and end keywords. Between start and end keywords there are multiple lines.

I want to print the first occurrence of the field coming between two matching patterns.

```
Start
<Frequency>125</Frequency>
<To>45</TO>

<Frequency>250</Frequency>
<To>67</TO>
End

Start
<Frequency>375</Frequency>
<To>89</TO>

<Frequency>250</Frequency>
<To>10</TO>

End
```

I want output which displays first occurrence of Frequency and To to be printed for each start and end.

The output should be like

```
125 45
375 89
```

Comment: Start <FreqStart> 125 <FreqEnd> <ToStart>45<ToEnd>

<FreqStart>250<FreqEnd> <ToStart>67<ToEnd> End

Start <FreqStart>375<FreqEnd> <ToStart>89<ToEnd>

<FreqStart>250<FreqEnd> <ToStart>10<ToEnd>

End

Comment: a sed would do. who on earth created such a messed up data format?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you want the number all listed on a single line, so I've used perl:

perl -ne 'print "$1 $2 " if /Start\D+(\d+)\D+(\d+)/; END{print "\n"}'

If more than one start can occupy the same record, use while and /g global mode like so:

perl -ne 'print "$1 $2 " while (/Start\D+(\d+)\D+(\d+)/g); END{print "\n"}'

Dash-n provides for automatic reading of the input, but allows you to control the output (i.e., does not automatically output every input line).